# Помогите расшифровать

Tags: пароль, шифрование

Есть зашифрованный пароль

> *4D7FEEE52C06843905F6EDA12A916A8A5E073781

Нужно расшифровать его и еще подскажите что за шифровка такая?

Comment: это пароль генерируется он в mysql через PASSWORD(); по моему

Comment: ну, если я расшифровала через md5, то получилось вот так abe695d9c82c8b31a1e77ccfe623302a     попробуй, может и подойдёт)))
или, это верно 997ed19e7ac472eb36284ed18bfadbd7
и может ещё это 5b1e879383746ca7f60b90663c467f54

//попробуй))))))0

Comment: > могу написать в лс.

Боюсь, что не можете.

Answer (score 2):

Напоминает sha1 или md5 с солью. Не расшифруете: это односторонняя функция - хэш функция.
Если совсем строго, то расшифруете. Но времени на это уйдет огромное количество.

Comment: и вариантов столько же

Comment: В случае с md5 в 16^8 меньше, надо заметить. ^___^

Comment: Можно расшифровать, но паролем воспользуются внуки :D

Comment: По длине - sha1. 

md5 покороче будет